# Windows Phone 8.1, rotating video is being cropped

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, video-player

I have to rotate a video, but I am having the following problem:

[image]

First one (top left) is the original video, as you can see, I have to rotate 90º. In landscape there is no problem (top right). But when I rotate in portrait (bottom left) the video is being cropped.

I think that the problem is that the video have a part outside the phone and that part is removed as you can see in the last three images (bottom right) (this is what I think, I am not sure if this is the problem).

This is my code:

```
stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

videoPlayer.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { Rotation = rot};

videoPlayer.SetSource(stream, file.FileType);
videoPlayer.Play()

Rect bounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
switch (rot) {
    case -90:
    case -270:
    case 90:
    case 270:
         videoPlayer.Height = bounds.Width;
         videoPlayer.Width = bounds.Height;
         break;
    default:
    case 0:
    case -180:
    case 180:
        videoPlayer.Height = bounds.Height;
        videoPlayer.Width = bounds.Width;
        break;
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<MediaElement Name="videoPlayer"
              AutoPlay="True"
              Stretch="Uniform"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              AreTransportControlsEnabled ="False"/>
```

Can someone tell me how to rotate the video without this cropping?

(The stretch value doesn't affect, I have tried all the possible values and nothing, same result)

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried setting your alignments to stretch instead of center?

Comment: Yeah, same problem :-/

Comment: Have you tried with different *Stretch* other than *Uniform*? Also have you tried setting height/width of *MediaElement*?

Comment: Assuming winphone xaml apps work roughly the same as wpf you shouldn't need to specify width and height when using align stretch just as a note, not sure if you made that change.

Comment: No, it doesn't goes well because it uses the size before rotation, it means that in portarit it is too small (because the height was before the width), and in landscape the height is too big.

Comment: @Romasz Yes, I tried others than Uniform and same. What do you mean with height/width of MediaElement? videoPlayer is the mediaElement and I am setting it by code.

Comment: Forget it, I've missed that you are setting them in code. Other thing - can you try to reset the *Stretch* property just after you set new width/height from code? Also is it possible that you can share a project with the problem?

Comment: @Romasz I tried rotating after change the sizes and same problem, how can I reset the strech property? Changing the value? I changed teh value and same result. Actually doesn't affect anything the stretch, can be uniform, uniform to fll, none, fill... always same result, even if I change after rotate, before, size... whatever.

Comment: I have no idea for the fix. Is it possible that you can share a sample working project?

Comment: @Romasz Just create a new universal app, in the xaml paste this:

Comment: <MediaElement Name="videoPlayer"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>

Comment: And at the end of the constructor (or if you prefer in the OnNavigatedTo)paste this:

Comment: videoPlayer.Source = new Uri("URL OF SOME VIDEO VIDEO");


            videoPlayer.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { Rotation = 90 };

            Rect bounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
            videoPlayer.Height = bounds.Width;
            videoPlayer.Width = bounds.Height;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think the problem with *cropping* is because of the *Grid* (or other) panel. It probably crops the video/mediaelement before rotating, so after this transform you see it as a square.

I've tried your code from the comment and managed to rotate video without cropping by using *Canvas*:

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Button x:Name="myBtn" Content="ClickMe button" Click="myBtn_Click"/>
    <MediaElement Name="myMedia" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
</Canvas>
```

```cs
private void myBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myMedia.Source = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Test.mp4");
    Rect bounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
    myMedia.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { Rotation = 90, TranslateX = -bounds.Width / 2 };
    double scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
    myMedia.Height = bounds.Width * scaleFactor;
    myMedia.Width = bounds.Height * scaleFactor;
}
```

Comment: Thank youuuuu :O¡You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

It works for wp8.1 Silverlight

```
<Grid>
  <Canvas Name="gdPlayer"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <MediaElement x:Name="player"
                      Stretch="Uniform"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5" />    
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

to rotate 90 degrees

```
player.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { Rotation = 90, TranslateX = -(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight / 2), TranslateY = -(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth / 2) };
player.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
player.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
```

to rotate 0 degrees

```
player.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { Rotation = 0, TranslateX = -(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth / 2), TranslateY = -(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight / 2) };
player.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
player.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
```